# Is hyperledger explorer realtime?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I have my network up and running based on the commercialPaper from hyperledger fabric docs,
I integrated hyperledger explorer to monitor updates but when transactions happen they don't appear on the dashboard instantly or after couple of minutes, so i have to restart docker containers (explorer, explorer-db) to see changes. Is there a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger explorer works in real-time. For simplicity, you can try the example of test-network. However, you also can check logs for commercial paper and share more detail of the configurations, connection profile and explorer logs.